# What is the maximum limit of users for single topic subscription in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am using Firebase topics to send notification.While doing so i came across the Firebase notification console which shows `(topic-name)<1000 estimated user` on selecting sending notification through topics

[image]

I have read this [POST](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging).It says `Firebase` can create unlimited topics.But my question is that how many maximum number of user can subscribe to a single topic because in console it showing `(topic-name)<1000 estimated user` and Firebase has not describe anything in doc about max limit users subscription to an individual topic.

If it has the limit of 1000 user to a single a topic subscription than what will happen when app excited this user limit.will it sent notification to first 1000 users of it will not send notification at all?

Comment: unlimted. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging watch the first list item

Comment: I have mentioned that post in my question.It says unlimited topic and subscription.its doesn't say anything about number of user to a single topic subscription and why they are showing <1000 estimated users ?

Comment: @teckwei is correct: there is no limit to how many users can be subscribed to a topic. The screenshot just shows that there are currently fewer than 1000 users subscribed to the topics listed.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hey.. Thx btw. Since you are enginner in google could you possible answer this for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211821/fcm-custom-notification-for-ios

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't found the answer link for you.But at 2015 GCM limit 1 million user to single topic subscription but which they already remove this limitation. FCM is using GCM as it core so which mean it is unlimited for user subscription to any topic.

You might get some point form this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375200/fcm-message-to-multiple-registration-ids-limit)

> We’re now happy to announce that we’re allowing unlimited free topics for your app. This means app developers can place an unlimited number of devices within each topic and create an unlimited number of topics.

By your second question that obviously told you that fcm estimated lesser than 1000 user subscribe to that topic. It's doesn't mean you cannot send to over 1000 device. You have misunderstading the meaning of < 1000 estimated users.